# Draw customized borders in R ggmap

Tags: r, ggmap

I can easily create US maps with county borders or state borders using R's ggmap routines. In my problem setting, I have a custom grouping of contiguous counties (that can possibly straddle state boundaries) and I only want to draw the borders of this custom group, i.e., not show the interior county borders within any custom group. Would really appreciate any pointers on how this can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making this type of map is possible using ggplot2 and sf.  It relies on using sf objects and the `sf::st_union()` function.

Non sf objects are usually easy to coerce using st_as_sf.

```
library(sf)

#Using the included nc dataset from sf package
nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))

# Arbitrarily select county near the middle of the state
single_county <- nc %>% filter(NAME == "Randolph")

single_county_plot <- ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data = nc) + 
  geom_sf(data = single_county, fill = 'red') +
  ggtitle('Single County, all borders')

#select all counties touching Randolph county
touching_single <- nc[st_touches(single_county, nc, sparse = FALSE),]

touching_plot <- ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data = nc) + 
  geom_sf(data = single_county, fill = 'red') + 
  geom_sf(data = touching_single, fill = 'green') +
  ggtitle('Multiple Counties,  all borders')

# Use st_union to join touching_single, which removes distinct boundaries
touching_unioned <- st_union(touching_single)

# Plotting it all
full_plot <- ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = nc) + 
  geom_sf(data = single_county, fill = 'red') + 
  geom_sf(data = touching_unioned, fill = 'green') + 
  ggtitle('All counties, some borders unioned')

full_plot_uncolored <- ggplot() +
       geom_sf(data = nc) + 
       geom_sf(data = single_county) + 
       geom_sf(data = touching_unioned) + 
       ggtitle('All counties, some borders unioned uncolored')

cowplot::plot_grid(single_county_plot, touching_plot, full_plot, full_plot_uncolored)
```

Below are plots showing the differences in county borders.  Using a color fill is not necessary, but was used to highlight the particular areas.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. This is a bit beyond my R skills but I will definitely give this a shot and get back to you with any questions.

Comment: Beyond your skills now, but keep working at it.  Lots of info here: https://www.r-spatial.org/